# Is Spring JdbcTemplate thread safe?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, ejb

I'm using Spring JdbcTemplate on one of my projects and now, when there are really very much requests with it - I started to face this exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; 
uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{? = call API.get_data_for_nb(?, ?)}]; 
SQL state [99999]; error code [17009]; Closed Statement; 
nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Closed Statement
```

So the Closed Statement exception is received when you try to execute statement that is already closed, but in my case I don't close it by myself - I use JdbcTemplate exactly for that. So, firstly, what could be the reason for that?

The JdbcTemplate object itself is contained in `@Stateless` EJB in this way:

```
@Stateless(name = "NbEdwServiceEJB")
public class NbEdwServiceBean implements NbEdwServiceLocal, NbEdwServiceRemote {

    @Resource(mappedName = JNDI)    
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private static volatile JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void construct() {
        synchronized (NbEdwServiceBean.class) {
            if (jdbcTemplate == null) {
                jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
                jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
            }
        }
    }

    private String getDataFromDB(final String request, final int isDigitalSignVerified) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            response = jdbcTemplate.execute(SQL_GET_DATA, new CallableStatementCallback<String>() {
                public String doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                    cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
                    cs.setInt(2, isDigitalSignVerified);
                    cs.setString(3, request);
                    cs.executeUpdate();
                    return cs.getString(1);
                }
            });
        } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("getDataFromDB()", ex);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

I know that this is maybe not the strictly right way to do it, I could just create instance of JdbcTemplate for every stateless bean - so I might do just that. So, secondly, why is this ever happening? My suppose was that JdbcTemplate's execute method isn't thread safe, but can someone give the full explanation on what is going on?

I have JEE version 5 running on WebLogic 10.3.5 if it's matter.

Comment: In the javadoc, it is stated that once configured a `JdbcTemplate` instance is thread-safe. It is hard to know, but the problem here could be more related to the fact that you set your static field `jdbcTemplate`  anytime an instance of `NbEdwServiceBean` is created while it should be done only once

Comment: If I were you, I would use another class annotated with `ApplicationScoped` that will manage  your `JdbcTemplate` instance, then inject the instance of this class in `NbEdwServiceBean`to get the `JdbcTemplate` instance, this will you will have only one instance of JdbcTemplate` instance in your application

Comment: @NicolasFilotto yes, It is good solution but in Java EE 5 I have no CDI and no Singleton and no applicationScoped beans

Comment: As you use a version of Java >= 5 , then you can wrap your `synchronized` block into a `if (jdbcTemplate == null) `, in other words you can use the *Double-Checked Locking* idiom to set `jdbcTemplate` only once.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Thread safety, depends from the case and sometimes it's  hard  to define. A major concurrency issue with Java DAOs is to protect a JDBC Connection, or EntityManager which are not thread safe. In the EJB world a Stateless Session bean would be used providing a thread per connection. Once a EJB DAO is in place, then each client would ask a separate DAO instance. It would be a major mistake, with EJBs, to try to inject to a singleton a DAO instance and letting escape from it, by providing an accessor. My experience with Spring is limited but your 2nd comment above makes me wonder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tolegen Izbassar I'm sorry that you're stuck with EE5.

Concerning the Singleton and EE5 there were some alternatives out there. One is vendor specific extensions, for example JBoss 5.x had service beans providing Singleton+JMX. A second solution is to use a earlier version of Jboss Seam compatible with EE5. A third alternative is to use the ServerContext from the Servlet API.

What you're trying to do in @PostConstuct is definitely not good. Non final statics in SLSB is a no go.

I suggest to have a look, at section 29.3 from Spring framework reference which describes  EJB - Spring integration, an example from that section:

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class MyFacadeEJB implements MyFacadeLocal {
// automatically injected with a matching Spring bean
@Autowired
private MyComponent myComp;
// for business method, delegate to POJO service impl.
public String myFacadeMethod(...) {
return myComp.myMethod(...);
}
```

Comment: So basically I have 3 solutions:
1. Provide vendor specific singletons (i could do one with WebLogic) - and use template from there.
2. Just make ```jdbcTemplate``` not static field - and create instance for every stateless bean, when container will need it.
3. Use some other frameworks, such as Spring, to provide singletons.

Thanks, now I understand what the problem is. So some other bean could already close connection - and the other bean, that is trying to execute statement is not good.

Comment: @Tolegen Izbassar my advice is to stay away from anything statefull including singletons as possible. What I think that is best is to wrap JdbcTempate inside a stateless bean following the example above. I'm not in the office write now to give you a concrete example but I can only recall that Spring configuration with JBoss 5.1 was a painful exercise.